# Passing options to ogr2ogr using python subprocess.Popen

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr, python-2.7, import

I'm trying to programmatically import some shapefiles to PostGIS, since I need to catch the exit code of the process I decided to use `subprocess.Popen`. I've managed to import the files using:

```
cmd = ["ogr2ogr","-f", "PostgreSQL", "PG:dbname=idegeo host=localhost port=5432      user=postgres password=postgres",
        "-nlt", "PROMOTE_TO_MULTI","-nln","tablename",
        "-unsetFieldWidth","shape.shp"]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

Now, the only thing I'm having problems is in passing the argument `--config PG_USE_COPY YES` to increase performance (as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109564/what-is-the-best-hack-for-importing-large-datasets-into-postgis/109604#109604%20here)).
I've  tried using `[someargs,"--config", "PG_USE_COPY YES"]` but Popen refuses to recognize the value passed to --config

Comment: Wouldn't you just put that in with your command (cmd) : cmd = ["ogr2ogr","--config PG_USE_COPY YES","-f",...

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson well, that was my original thought but Popen expects arguments in pairs as in `["-f","PostgreSQL"]` so if i pass the full string `"--config PG_USE_COPY YES"`I get `Unknown option name '--config PG_USE_COPY YES'`

Comment: if "--config PG_USE_COPY YES" doesn't work try "--config","PG_USE_COPY YES"

Comment: Well, it turns out that the correct option is `["ogr2ogr","--config" ,"PG_USE_COPY", "YES"..]`

Comment: Can you put that in as an answer (yes, answer your own question) - answers are searchable, comments are not, and I am sure that someone will have the same or similar problem and your answer would benefit them.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm answering my own question in case someone runs into the same issue:

To pass the option `--config PG_USE_COPY YES` to `Popen` you have to pass it as three separate strings:

```
cmd = [...someArgs,"--config" ,"PG_USE_COPY", "YES", ...someMoreArgs]
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for writing out that answer, the docs on the popen can be a little confusing; when to put in separate arguments and when joined arguments are acceptable can be a little hit and miss.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson No problem. As a rule of thumb, you should always separate arguments