# Data limits & runtime of shp2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql, bash

I am using shp2pgsql in a bash script to import shapefiles into postgres. I can successfully do this for shapefiles with hundreds of records however shapefiles with tens of thousands of records (in this case ~40,000) hangs so I have to use the postGIS shapefile importer in pgAdmin (which works ~30-45 seconds to complete).

I realize it's a substantial jump in magnitude regarding the number of records. Is it possible if I wait long enough it will succeed?

what are the runtime/data limits for shp2pgsql?

Comment: Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109564/what-is-the-best-hack-for-importing-large-datasets-into-postgis and try shp2pgsql with -D switch. I also suppose that the shapefile importer in pgAdmin actually is shp2pgsql.

Comment: @user30184 that did the trick! I think you are correct that shp2pgsql is just the command line for the importer.