# ogr2ogr slow to load ArcGIS file geodatabase data into PostgreSQL

Tags: gdal, postgresql, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

**Problem:** Using ogr2ogr to transfer feature sets and attribute tables from ArcGIS file geodatabases to a PostgreSQL database is taking unnecessarily long. For instance, regardless of machine I am working on, it takes roughly two days to load a table with 9 million rows; each row has five attributes with formats of double precision, integer, integer, varchar(55), and double precision. I am looking for help because this is going to be an on-going task and I am trying to develop a repeatable work process.

**What I am hoping to find out:** I have done some searches on speeding up ogr2ogr and PostgreSQL, but the most common suggestions have not sped things up. My guess is there is either a flag I am missing in ogr2ogr or a setting I am overlooking in postgresql.conf that I need.

**What I have tried:**
The ogr2ogr command format I am using is:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -overwrite -skipfailures --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=*hostip* user=*username* dbname=*databasename* password=*userpassword*" "C:\pathTo\GDBName.gdb" "*tablename*"
```

Based on PostgreSQL tuning recommendations I found, I made the following changes to postgresql.conf:

- shared_buffers - increased to 500MB
- temp_buffers - increased to 32MB
- work_mem - increased to 32MB
- maintenance_work_mem - enabled but left default value (64MB)
- wal_buffers - increased to 8MB
- checkpoint_timeout - increased to 15min
- max_wal_size - increased to 15GB
- checkpoint_completion_target - increased to 0.85

**Environment:**

- PostgreSQL computer - Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit), Intel Xeon CPU (2.6GHZ), 16GB RAM, PostgreSQL 9.5 with PostGIS. This is **not** an ESRI Enterprise Database (SDE).
- Data source computers (various) - So far I have used Windows 7, Windows 10, and Ubuntu 17.04 computers to run ogr2ogr. All have 8GB RAM and CPUs that are 2-3 years old. All are using GDAL 2.2.1.

**Note: I know the PostgreSQL database can load feature sets and attribute tables from a file geodatabase quickly. I first loaded my data using ArcCatalog 10.5 and everything loaded quickly. The large tables took 2-4 hours on average as opposed to the 2 days to 1.5 weeks ogr2ogr is taking. The problem with ArcCatalog, and the reason I am using ogr2ogr, is that it converted all the double precision ID fields to integer, which made the ID fields useless.

While corrupted, the fact that the database did load large (to me) tables rapidly using ArcCatalog is why I am assuming I have overlooked a simple configuration tweak.

Comment: I use the same commands as you when doing this task. shot in the dark here but maybe try loading it into a specific schema???...

Comment: 9 million rows is a pretty absurdly large dataset... but you said you loaded it in 2-4 hours through arcatalog into postgres? thats a large discrepancy

Comment: another option might be to turn of the spatial index when importing it. it may be faster to create it after the data is in the DB. -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=OFF

Comment: Your system is for some reason exceptionally slow. With a normal laptop with local PostGIS the normal speed is close to 1 million inserted polygons per minute https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109564/what-is-the-best-hack-for-importing-large-datasets-into-postgis. That would mean no more than 20 minutes with your data.  I would make a test by writing data first into an interim shapefile. Perhaps the slow component is not writing to PostGIS but reading the geodatabase. Add `--debug on` into your ogr2ogr command for getting more info for debugging.

Comment: @ziggy, I am only loading attribute tables so far, have not gotten to the shapes yet. I will keep the -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=OFF tip in mind when I get to those.

Comment: @user30184, of course I forgot to set --debug on. Once my current loads complete this evening (PST) I will add turn debug on and load some smaller tables to see what gets returned. I will update tomorrow (9/28).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After turning debug on the problem became clear. [face palm]

ogr2ogr was encountering an error on every row it was adding to the PostgreSQL table it created. The error was caused because the numeric IDs are expressed as 14 digit whole numbers, which is why they are all formatted as double precision rather than integer. As ogr2ogr was creating tables on the fly and populating them it saw the whole numbers as integers, threw a COPY error, and then accepted it was double precision (I assume from the format information the file geodatabase keeps) and put the correct values in the table.

The problem was solved by setting up the table structure in PostgreSQL first and then using the -update, -append, and -nln flags. What had taken 46 minutes on my test table using the ogr2ogr command from my question took only 5 seconds after adding those flags as no errors occurred while loading the rows.

Setting up each table in PostgreSQL prior to loading the data will be tedious (there are 155 tables in the file geodatabases), but as this is an annual task I can either dump/load the schema structure each year or update and rerun the table building SQL. It is a fair amount of upfront work, but loading the data each subsequent year will be significantly faster than the first attempt.

The ogr2ogr command format is now:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=hostip user=username dbname=databasename password=userpassword" "C:\pathTo\GDBName.gdb" -nln schema.existingtable "gdbtablename" --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

Comment: if I were you I'd try and use python to create those 155 tables, thats a large amount of manual labor

Comment: @ziggy, I hear you. Sped things up by writing a long SQL script and got all the tables set up this morning.  Learning python is next on my work plan.  :)